# xlsread function with very small number matlab

Tags: matlab, xlsread

I want to use xlsread function in matlab to import very small data like 10E-13. But it always shows 0 in vector 'num'. I want to read the exact number and export it.

So, does anyone know how to increase the accuracy or precision?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Would be helpful for you to show example command and command window output.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the precision with which `xlsread` reads the data.  However, the output array might actually contain the data in `num`, but MATLAB displays it as `0`.  Run `format long g`, then diplay it again.